# nw-builder - Menus in windows64 build with version 0.12.2 are not shown

Tags: menu, nw.js

In windows 64 build with  0.12.2, menu is not getting displayed, it works fine in linux64. Below is the code for menu, please guide what is missing.

`var gui = require('nw.gui');
    var menu = new gui.Menu({ type: 'menubar' });
    var submenu = new gui.Menu();
    $scope.goToLogin = function() {
        //gui.Window.get().menu = null;
        $location.path('/login');
        $scope.$apply();
    };
    submenu.append(new gui.MenuItem({
        label: 'Logout',
        click: $scope.goToLogin,
        key: "o",
        modifiers: "ctrl+alt"
    }));
    submenu.append(new gui.MenuItem({ label: 'Item B' }));
    menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({
        label: 'Options',
        submenu: submenu
    }));
    gui.Window.get().menu = menu;`

Tried with other versions of nw-builder like 0.15.0-beta1, 0.15.0-beta2 - but getting bellow error

{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-webkit-builder/cache/0.15.0-beta1/win64/ffmpegsumo.dll']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-webkit-builder/cache/0.15.0-beta1/win64/ffmpegsumo.dll' }

Comment: How about using version 0.14.4 instead of using betas? The error is a [known issue](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-builder/issues/252)

Comment: Yeah, tried with 0.14.x versions after updating platforms.js, now able to get menus in windows os too, but now in linux getting shareable file instead of executable file of nw :(